# android fragment webview loading indicator

Tags: android, eclipse, screen, splash-screen

I would like to add loading indicator to my webview is there any solution for it?

thank you in advance!!

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Showing_now extends SherlockFragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_showing_now, container, false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webViewsn);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.myweburl.com");
    return mainView;
}
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ActionbarSherlock, and the Android Support Library, I suggest using this setup

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            setSupportProgress(progress * 100);
            if (progress == 100) {
                setSupportProgressBarVisibility(false);
            }
        }
    });
    webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

So pretty much, you just need to call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS)` before you set your `ContentView` and after that, use `setSupportProgressBarVisibility(true);` to set the `ProgressBar` on create when your `webview` first loads. To get the progressview to stop whenever your content is finished loading, you would create a new `WebChromeClient` and add `OnProgressChanged` and set the `ProgressBar`'s visibility to false whenever the progress reaches 100%

Comment: i try to use it but its not working can you please tell me where i should add it?

Comment: All of this code should be in `onCreate` when you initialize your activity. What exactly is it that fails? Do you get a `NullPointerException`? Also, since it seems you're using fragments, you might have to tweak my code a bit. instead of using `this`, try `getActivity()`